# Log In Attendance System using Php Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am late in Codeigniter, By the way I am coming to my Question...
"I need to make a 'Online Attendance System' and here I am using Php and Mysql as Developing tools. I have done soo many things like.....
1) User Reg -> Admin Activation -> then User Active
2) User Can Login -> Mark Attendance for him -> If he Logout, Put time for Logout and Calculate working Hours.
3) Then User can Re Login -> Then Time will count from the last working time of the same day.
4) Then have done additonal Functionalities...

Troubled In..... When Session Out or Network Issues or System Shutdown, I cannot calculate End Time or Logout Time.

I know we can Store in Cookies, But here I cannot Use it Because for the security.

Any solutions..????? It is my Challenging Web App, Can i hope to Finish..?????

Comment: I realise there is probably a language barrier, but as it's very hard to understand what you're asking here. It might help you to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank U, I am fresher here.... So pls Excuse. Language Barrier.!! No Other Solutions.???